# Buttons aligned at top right in TabControl?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

In VB.Net, is there a way in a TabControl to make the tabs appear at the top, but on the right-hand side instead of the left?

Online I've found plenty of methods for right-alignment with horizontal text, which is well documented, but what I'm after is top alignment, but with the buttons stacked to the right rather than the left of the panel.

'RightToLeft' doesn't appear to have the desired effect.

Thanks very much

Comment: Also change RightToLeftLayout.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried both options singularly, but can't believe I didn't try them both at the same time.

Comment: Also, there's a QuickTime object on one of my tabs, and changing the setting to Right-To-Left has a strange effect on the QuickTime object's movie controller bar, so I may just leave it as-is after all.